# Type guard not resolving from computed property

Tags: typescript, casting

For some reason `TypeScript` is not able to resolve a *type-guard* when it is placed in a computed property.

The following code resolves properly:

```js
class Timeout {
    protected timer? : NodeJS.Timeout

    start() {
        if (this.timer !== undefined) { // <-- type-guard
            clearTimeout(this.timer)
        }
    }
}
```

However, when the `if` conditional is extracted to a computed property *(seen below)* it is not resoled by `TypeScript`.

```js
class Timeout {
    protected timer? : NodeJS.Timeout

    start() {
        if (this.hasStarted) {
            clearTimeout(this.timer)
        }
    }

    get hasStarted() {
        return this.timer !== undefined 
    }
}
```

**How can I force the type guard to resolve without having to `cast` the value to a `non-null` type?**

Comment: possible with a method (which will be a type guard) and a public property.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: It cannot resolve property in an object (`this` in this case) and do type-narrowing.
If you do `const timer = this.timer; if (timer !== undefined) { ... }` it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript will not generally follow code across function boundaries to check for side effects. So moving the checks to a separate function will kill flow analysis. The only exception to this is a custom type guard which has special syntax to let the compiler know that the type of a parameter has changed.

```
class Timeout {
    timer? : NodeJS.Timeout
    hasStarted() :this is this & { timer : NodeJS.Timeout } {
        return this.timer != null;
    }
    start() {
        if (this.hasStarted()) {
            clearTimeout(this.timer)
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** this will only work on public fields.

**Note:** I'm not recommending this necessarily, but present it just for the sake of completeness and due to comment demand.

Answer (score 1):

A property comparison is not considered as a type guard.

If you want to do type guard inline, you can do this:

```
class Timeout {
    protected timer? : NodeJS.Timeout

    start() {
        const timer = this.timer
        if (timer !== undefined) {
            clearTimeout(timer)
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can let the compiler know you are smarter:

```
class Timeout {
    protected timer? : NodeJS.Timeout

    start() {
        if (this.timer !== undefined) {
            clearTimeout(this.timer!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I proposed in my question, I don’t see how I can utilize the computer property to do this comparison for me

Comment: Neither are casting it to non-null.
The first one is what's need to do a type guard. TypeScript does not do it on property. The second one is giving additional info to compiler with `!`. That does not cast the variable per se. The vanilla `this.timer` still have type `NodeJS.Timeout | undefined`